# Visual Studio 2015 not updating .exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have updated the c# code in my VS project but when I build it the .exe file is not updated.

I've tried:

1. clicking 'rebuild' in visual studio
2. deleting the files from my bin/debug folder and recreating them, the .exe still has the old date modified but the .dll files have the correct date modified
3. closing and re-opening the project in vs 2015
4. having the project as the only one within vs

I expect the date modified of the .exe file to be todays date but it is not, it is the prev date modified date of over a year ago.

Comment: try, intializing a random variable and rebuild, or restarting your machine, sometimes when visual studio doesn't detect code change it doesn't rebuild the existing application

Comment: *deleting the files from my bin/debug folder and recreating them, the .exe* - wait, how come that deleting the exe which was then regenerated by VS still got the old date? What am I missing?

Comment: It's impossible for you to delete the files from your bin/debug folder and then have the .exe come back with the old date. Are you sure you're doing a debug build? If you're looking at the debug folder, but your new executable is in release, clearly you won't notice the updated executable.

Comment: @meJustAndrew tried both of those things an still the .exe has the old modified date

Comment: @KenWhite My build configuration is set to bin/Debug, I delete the files, open the project, rebuild it, new files appear with the .dll file having todays date as the modified date but the .exe file has an old modified date

Comment: @meJustAndrew That is what is really confusing. So before I open the project I make sure the debug folder is empty. I open the project, click rebuild and the files are generated, some with todays date but the .exe file is the old modified date as is the vshost.exe file. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: so the exe file at which you are looking is located also under the Debug folder which was previously empty? (sorry if asking the obvious, but I have to be sure)

Comment: Use your explorer to find all files with an identical_name.exe.  check the dates.

Comment: Again, it's **impossible** for you to delete all files from your bin/debug folder and then build and have the old executable appear with the old date. VS does not back-date files in the bin/debug folder, and it does not replace them with old versions when you delete and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Something else to consider is in Options there are settings under Build and Run that could be set to build older versions if either the project is out of date or if build errors occur.  Meaning that it will build the last successful build instead of the most recent.  What does your build Output say?  That would be a good place to check as well.

Comment: In the Build and Run settings I don't see anything to indicate it should build older versions:
On Run, when projects are out of date = Prompt to build
On Run, when build or deployment errors occur = Prompt to build

My output says: Rebuild All: 1 succeeded and there's no errors listed above this

Comment: Is the checkbox for "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" checked on or off? It should be checked off as well

Answer (score 0):

Make sure every project and solution has same build configuration selected. You might have some projects configured to output to bin/release and some to bin/debug. Not enough info to say for sure.

As how to find build configuration:
VS has feature called Configuration Manager. In default layout and settings is available from drop-down menu on your toolbar with values like 'Debug' and 'Release'. Go to project properties (right-click on project node in solution explorer) and find "Build" tab; you will find there same drop-down menu.

Comment: It is building to the Debug folder in both the drop down list at the top of VS and the build tab of the project properties. I only have this project in the solution.